# Graphing the complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm looking for some software that my help me to graph some complex functions on unit circle. I.e. let say if I have $\ f(z)=1/(1-z)$ I want to see to give an input an image with unit circle and want to get the transformed image of unit circle with $\ f(z)$ function.

Can anybody suggest some grapher for this, or something similar ?

Comment: Try Sage, http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/complex_plot.html

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28+1%2F%281-z%29%29

Comment: I believe what you are describing is called Mapping.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712930/complex-function-mapping-the-unit-circle-onto-an-interval

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free software / online tool to plot complex functions as maps of grids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399467/free-software-online-tool-to-plot-complex-functions-as-maps-of-grids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this guide to Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/plot/complex_plot.html): to using [Sage Online](http://www.sagenb.org/) if you don't want to install Sage on your computer.

Graphing $\frac{1}{1-z}$ that way yeilds:

[image]

Graphing $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ that way yields:

[image]

It would be nice to see it in 3D instead of merely color coded. The y-axis is coming out of the picture toward us and instead of seeing the surface that is desired we see a color-graph. I have [asked that question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448397/graphing-compex-functions-3d-x-y-i-axes-instead-of-color-coded-sage)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your are plotting 1/(1+z) instead of 1/(1-z).

Comment: Amazing that this is the accepted answer when it does not answer the question at all...

Comment: @Dale I kindly mean that the formula you plotted `1/(1+z)` is not the same as the one you introduce (`1/(1-z)`). The freeware is not faulty there, just the input formula is.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28+1%2F%281%2Bz%29%29

Comment: @Dale Your link is still wrong compared to what you introduce. You say 1/(1-z) but both your representation and the link are 1/(1+z) (the zero of your function is -1). Please have a closer look.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of Möbius transformations, you don't need any software. Consider the map $f : \overline{\mathbb{C}}_z \to \overline{\mathbb{C}}_w$ given by $w = (1-z)^{-1}$. It follows that $z = (w-1)w^{-1}$. If $|z| = 1$ then $|(w-1)w^{-1}| = 1$ and so $|w| = |w-1|$. The image of the unit circle is the perpendicular bisector of $w=0$ and $w=1$, i.e. the line parallel to the imaginary axis that passes through $w = \frac{1}{2}$.

In general, if $f : \overline{\mathbb{C}}_z \to \overline{\mathbb{C}}_w$ is given by

$$w = \frac{az + b}{cz + d} \, . $$

where $(a:b:c:d) \in \mathbb{CP}^3$ then

$$z = \frac{dw-b}{cw-a} \, . $$

The image of the unit circle is given by setting $|z| = 1$ and so $|cw-a| = |dw-b|$ is the equation of the image in the $w$-sphere.

Comment: the example function in my question is just a sample. I need visually see the transformation of unit circle with any complex function. So that why I need software

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204229/mapping-circles-using-m%C3%B6bius-transformations?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For that, you can use Reflex4You.com. Normally it is a ray-tracing engine, but you can make it work to find the image of your circle.
The identity function looks like this:

[image: identity]

A function describing the unit circle with colors on a black background is the following:

```
if((abs(z)>0.9)*(abs(z)<1.1),z,0)
```

[image: if((abs(z)>0.9)*(abs(z)<1.1),z,0)]

The function you are invoking has the following representation:

[image: 1/(1-z)]

To see what the circle becomes through the function, you can use the following code:

`set k = 0;
let n = 100;
let f = 1/(1-z);
set result = 0;
let threshold = 0.1;
repeat n in
set theta = exp(i*2*pi*k/n);
set result = if(abs(f(theta)-z) < threshold, theta, result);
set k = k + 1;
result`

[image: Function described above]

Edit it yourself: Click on the image above.

If you know the inverse of the function (if it exist) then you can print it faster. In our case, $f^{(-1)}=1-\frac{1}{z}$, so that you can write the formula:

`let w = 1-1/z;
let c= if((abs(z)>0.9)*(abs(z)<1.1),z,0);
o(c,w)`

[image: Smooth version of the image of the circle]

DISCLAIMER: I am one of the authors of this website which can also serves the purpose of customized object store.