# How To Slice $Re(1/(1+z))$ Into A Cartesian Function For Any Angle?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, terminology, graphing-functions

The complex function $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$  may be [broken into real and imaginary components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448397/graphing-compex-functions-3d-x-y-i-axes-instead-of-color-coded-sage/462637#462637):

$$Re \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}\bigg)=\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$

$$Im \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}\bigg)=\frac{-2xyi}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$

Graphing the real components and colouring them according to the imaginary components yields:

[image]

Slicing the graph of the real components along the x-axis yeilds the graph of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, which is:

[image]

Slicing the graph of the real components along the y-axis yields the graph of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$, which is:

[image]

Is it possible to write a cartesian equation equivalent to slicing the above 3D graph of $Re(1/(1+z))$ for any angle between the x and y axes?

For your convenience see the [graph the $Re(1/(1+z^2))$ on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-y%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*y%5E2%29&dataset=)!

[image]

Note that graphing the imaginary components [yields something entirely different](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2xy%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2%2b4x%5E2y%5E2%29).

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would be setting $y = c\cdot x$ in the expression for the real/imaginary part.

Comment: @DanielFischer How would c relate to the angle?

Comment: $c = \tan \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the angle to the positive real axis. You can write $z = x+iy = r(\cos\varphi + i\sin\varphi)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you like me to write that up as the answer or would you prefer to?

Comment: Go ahead, you know better what you desire.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have some follow up questions. How can the axis of rotation be separated from the origin? How can the angle of the axis be made skew relative to the z-axis? Finally, where did you learn to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you interested in a slice of the graph along a line not passing through the origin, or do you want a view of the graph from a different point and angle? In the former case, I'd reparametrise the function. The line has a parametrisation $a + t e^{i\varphi},\; t\in\mathbb{R}$ with fixed $\varphi$, and graphing $g(t) = f(a + te^{i\varphi})$ would give the desired view. In the latter case, I'm not sure how to do it, I don't know much about plotting.

Comment: Consider asking a new question, there's more space to explain your needs there than in comments, and someone with experience in plotting functions may have a good answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer you have got the idea: a slice along a line not passing through the origin. I wrote up the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108049/how-to-slice-a-complex-functions-about-an-axis-that-is-not-though-the-origin-and

Comment: Use `\Re(z)` for $\Re(z)$ or `\operatorname{Re}(z)` for $\operatorname{Re}(z)$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor please help me understand what you are answering.

Comment: @Dale I’m answering nothing, hence why I commented instead of posting an answer. I figured that an esteemed user such as yourself would appreciate advice on how to improve formatting

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor thank you for saying it was about formatting. I assumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Fischer explained in the comments rotating the vertical plane that cuts through the real component of the complex function $Re(1/(1+z)$ or even for $In(1/(1+z))$ is as simple as setting $y=c \cdot x$ where $c=tan(\theta)$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the vertical plane and the positive real axis. $y=c\cdot x=tan(\theta)$.

For example: given that

$$Re(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)})=\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$

replacing the y with $tan(\theta)\cdot x$:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(\theta)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(\theta)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(\theta)*x)^2}$$

[Setting $\theta=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%5E2-(x*tan(0))%5E2)%2F((1%2Bx%5E2-(x*tan(0))%5E2)%5E2%2B4*x%5E2*(x*tan(0))%5E2)) gives the answer in the question:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(0)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(0)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(0)*x)^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

[Setting $\theta=45$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29) creates a nice clean Cartesian equation:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(45)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(45)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(45)*x)^2}=\frac{1}{4x^4+1}$$

Most values of theta such as [$\theta=44$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2844%29%29%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2844%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28x*tan%2844%29%29%5E2%29) doesn't reduce or approximate cleanly at all like $\theta =45$ does:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(44)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(44)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(44)*x)^2}$$

However [$\theta = 30$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2830%29%29%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2830%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28x*tan%2830%29%29%5E2%29) does reduce nicely:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(30)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(30)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(30)*x)^2}=
\frac{\frac{2x^2}{3}+1}{\frac{4x^4}{3}+(\frac{2x^2}{3}+1)^2}=\frac{6x^2+9}{16x^4+12x^2+9}$$

As does [$\theta = 60$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2860%29%29%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2860%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28x*tan%2860%29%29%5E2%29):

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(60)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(60)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(60)*x)^2}=
\frac{1-2x^2}{12x^4+(1-2x^2)^2}=\frac{1-2x^2}{16x^4-4x^2+1}$$

[Setting $\theta=90$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28x*tan%2845%29%29%5E2%29) gives:

$$\frac{1+x^2-(tan(90)*x)^2}{(1+x^2-(tan(90)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(90)*x)^2}=Undefined$$ This was supposed to equal $$ \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

So I tried [switching the parameter](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%280%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%280%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%280%29*x%29%5E2%29) being substituted to: 
$$\frac{1+(tan(90)*y)^2-y^2}{(1+(tan(90)*y)^2-y^2)^2+4(tan(90)*y)^2y^2}= \frac{1}{1-y^2}$$

The [graph of $\frac{1}{1-y^2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D1%2F(1-y%5E2)) looks identical to $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$

While the Question didn't ask for analysis of the imaginary component:

$$Im(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)})=\frac{-2xy}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$

replacing the y with $tan(\theta)\cdot x$:

$$\frac{-2x(tan(\theta)*x)}{(1+x^2-(tan(\theta)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(\theta)*x)^2}$$

Setting [$\theta=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%280%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%280%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%280%29*x%29%5E2%29) creates a nice clean Cartesian equation:

$$\frac{-2x(tan(0)*x)i}{(1+x^2-(tan(0)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(0)*x)^2}=0$$

Setting [$\theta=30$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%2830%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%2830%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%2830%29*x%29%5E2%29):

$$\frac{-2x(tan(30)*x)i}{(1+x^2-(tan(30)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(30)*x)^2}=\frac{-6\sqrt{3}x^2}{16x^4+12x^2+9}$$

Setting [$\theta=45$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%2845%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%2845%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%2845%29*x%29%5E2%29):

$$\frac{-2x(tan(45)*x)i}{(1+x^2-(tan(45)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(45)*x)^2}=\frac{-2x^2}{4x^4+1}$$

Setting [$\theta=60$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%2860%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%2860%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%2860%29*x%29%5E2%29):

$$\frac{-2x(tan(60)*x)i}{(1+x^2-(tan(60)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(60)*x)^2}=\frac{-2\sqrt{3}x^2}{16x^4-4x^2+1}$$

Setting [$\theta=90$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2*x*%28tan%2890%29*x%29%29/%28%281%2bx%5E2-%28tan%2890%29*x%29%5E2%29%5E2%2b4*x%5E2*%28tan%2890%29*x%29%5E2%29):

$$\frac{-2x(tan(90)*x)i}{(1+x^2-(tan(90)*x)^2)^2+4x^2(tan(90)*x)^2}=Indeterminate$$

$$Im \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}\bigg)=\frac{-2xyi}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$ Where y=1,

$$Im \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)}\bigg)=\frac{-2xi}{(1+x^2-1)^2+4x^2}$$

[If y=1,](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%5E2-(1%5E2))%2F((1%2Bx%5E2-(1)%5E2)%5E2%2B4*x%5E2*(1)%5E2)) then: 
 $$(1 + x^2 - 1^2)/((1 + x^2 - 1^2)^2 + 4 x^2×1^2)=x^2/(x^4 + 4 x^2)$$
 Maybe try rotating the surface instead of slicing at an angle. 
[How to rotate the graph $z=f(x)$ towards $y$ so that $z=f(x,y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746387/how-to-rotate-the-graph-z-fx-towards-y-so-that-z-fx-y/2749323#2749323)

x' = x cos(theta) +y sin(theta) , y'=-x sin(theta)+y cos(theta)

z=x^3 becomes:
z=(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^3

$$Re(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)})=\frac{1+(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2-( -x sin(45)+y cos(45) )^2}{(1+(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2-(-x sin(45)+y cos(45))^2)^2+4(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2(-x sin(45)+y cos(45))^2}$$

\frac{1+ (x*cos45+y*sin45) ^2-( -x sin(45)+y cos(45) )^2}{(1+(x*cos45+y*sin45)^2- (-x sin(45)+y cos(45))^2)^2+4 (x*cos45+y*sin45) ^2(-x sin(45)+y cos(45))^2}

Wolfarm Alpha reduced this too: 
$$\frac{(2 x y + 1)}{(x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + 4 x y + y^4 + 1)}$$

[WOlfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(xcos45%2Bysin45)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20cos(45)%2By%20cos(45)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(xcos45%2Bysin45)%5E2-%20(-x%20cos(45)%2By%20cos(45))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(xcos45%2Bysin45)%20%5E2(-x%20cos(45)%2By%20cos(45))%5E2%7D)

y=x*tan(0)

$$\frac{1+ (x*cos45+x*tan(0)*sin45) ^2-( -x sin(45)+x*tan(0)
 cos(45) )^2}{(1+(x*cos45+x*tan(0)
*sin45)^2- (-x sin(45)+x*tan(0)
 cos(45))^2)^2+4 (x*cos45+x*tan(0)
*sin45) ^2(-x sin(45)+x*tan(0)
 cos(45))^2}= \frac{1}{(x^4 + 1)}$$

tan(0)=0

$$\frac{1+ (x*cos45) ^2-( -x sin(45))^2}{(1+(x*cos45)^2- (-x sin(45))^2)^2+4 (x*cos45) ^2(-x sin(45))^2}= \frac{1}{(x^4 + 1)}$$

This answer agrees 100% with BernardK's answer and Is likely a superior way of slicing that I did above.
[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(x*cos45%2Bx*tan(0)*sin45)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20cos(45)%2Bx*tan(0)cos(45)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(x*cos45%2Bx*tan(0)*sin45)%5E2-%20(-x%20cos(45)%2Bx*tan(0)%20cos(45))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(x*cos45%2Bx*tan(0)*sin45)%20%5E2(-x%20cos(45)%2Bx*tan(0)%20cos(45))%5E2%7D)

[image]

theta=30
$$\frac{1+ (xcos30+ysin30) ^2-( -x sin(30)+y cos(30) )^2}{(1+(xcos30+ysin30)^2- (-x sin(30)+y cos(30))^2)^2+4 (xcos30+ysin30) ^2(-x sin(30)+y cos(30))^2}$$
[y=tan(0)=0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(xcos30)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20cos(30)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(xcos30)%5E2-%20(-x%20cos(30))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(xcos30)%20%5E2(-x%20cos(30))%5E2%7D)
$$\frac{1+ (xcos30) ^2-( -x sin(30) )^2}{(1+(xcos30)^2- (-x sin(30))^2)^2+4 (xcos30) ^2(-x sin(30))^2}=\frac{1}{((\frac{9}{4}x^4) + 1)}
$$
[Theta=20](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(xcos20)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20cos(20)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(xcos20)%5E2-%20(-x%20cos(20))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(xcos20)%20%5E2(-x%20cos(20))%5E2%7D)
$$\frac{1+ (xcos20) ^2-( -x sin(20) )^2}{(1+(xcos20)^2- (-x sin(20))^2)^2+4 (xcos20) ^2(-x sin(20))^2}=\frac{1}{(4 x^4 cos(20°)^4 + 1)}$$

[Theta=2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(xcos2%2Bysin2)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20sin(2)%2By%20cos(2)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(xcos2%2Bysin2)%5E2-%20(-x%20sin(2)%2By%20cos(2))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(xcos2%2Bysin2)%20%5E2(-x%20sin(2)%2By%20cos(2))%5E2%7D)
$$\frac{1+ (xcos2+ysin2) ^2-( -x sin(2)+y cos(2) )^2}{(1+(xcos2+ysin2)^2- (-x sin(2)+y cos(2))^2)^2+4 (xcos2+ysin2) ^2(-x sin(2)+y cos(2))^2}$$

[THeta=90](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%20(xcos90%2Bysin90)%20%5E2-(%20-x%20cos(90)%2By%20cos(90)%20)%5E2%7D%7B(1%2B(xcos90%2Bysin90)%5E2-%20(-x%20cos(90)%2By%20cos(90))%5E2)%5E2%2B4%20(xcos90%2Bysin90)%20%5E2(-x%20cos(90)%2By%20cos(90))%5E2%7D) This was supposed to rotate the surface not slice it along the y axis.

Note that the z=2 curve is the lemniscate of Bernoulli. 
[How to match my curve with the correct lemniscate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753708/how-to-match-my-curve-with-the-correct-lemniscate/2753901#2753901)

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138808/plotting-a-2d-slice-of-a-3d-function

Comment: It is quite surprising how the different angles of slices relate various functions to the original complex function.   Now graph Re{ (-2z^2)/(4z^4+1)}.  (-2(x+I*y)^2)/(4(x+I*y)^4+1).

Comment: (-2(tan(45)+I*y)^2)/(4((tan(45)+I*y)^4+1)

Comment: (-2(tan(30)+I*y)^2)/(4((tan(30)+I*y)^4+1)

Comment: (-2(tan(0)+I*y)^2)/(4((tan(0)+I*y)^4+1) =

Comment: (-2(tan(0)+Iy)^2)/(4((tan(0)+Iy)^4+1) =y^2/(2*(y^4+1))

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-2(x%2BIy)%5E2)%2F(4(x%2BIy)%5E4%2B1)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2%2F(2*(y%5E4%2B1))

Comment: (x+i*y)^2/(2*((x+i*y)^4+1)) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2Bi*y)%5E2%2F(2*((x%2Bi*y)%5E4%2B1))

Comment: (1+x^2-(x*tan(45))^2)/((1+x^2-(x*tan(45))^2)^2+4*x^2*(x*tan(45))^2)=tan(45)

Comment: (-2*(x+I*y)^4)/(4*(x+I*y)2+1)

Comment: (-2*(tan(theta)+I*y)^4)/(4*((tan(theta)+I*y)^2+1)

Comment: (-2*(tan(0)+I*y)^4)/(4*((tan(0)+I*y)^2+1)

Comment: (-2*(tan(theta)+Iy)^2)/(4*((tan(theta)+Iy)^4+1)

Comment: (-2*(tan(0)+Iy)^4)/((4*(tan(0)+Iy)^2+1)  and 1/(z^2+1)  x=tan(0) both contain (-2x^2)/(4*x^4+1)

Answer (score 1):

Recapitulating the question with just a little extra notation, 
we have two real functions
$$f(z) = \mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)$$
and
$$g(z) = \mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right).$$

Taking $z = x + iy,$
we can plot one of these functions (for example, $f$) in three dimensions
by labeling the three axes $x,$ $y,$ and $w$ (using $w$ for the third axis since we've already used $z$ for something else)
and plotting the equation
$$ w = f(x + iy).$$

Now we want to "slice" this plot along one of the planes through the
origin perpendicular to the $x,y$ plane,
that is, we want a slice along a plane containing the $w$-axis,
but rotated an angle $\theta$ away from the $x$-axis.
Because complex analysis is involved here, 
let's measure $\theta$ in radians rather than degrees.
(This will simplify some formulas later.)
We might as well assume $\theta \in [0, \pi),$at least for now,
because every other angle will slice the three-dimensional graph
along one of the planes described by $\theta \in [0, \pi).$

This slice can then be viewed as a graph in two dimensions.
Naturally, we might expect to be able to impose a Cartesian coordinate system on this plane so that we can write an equation for the graph.
Since the $w$ axis already lies in the plane, it is an obvious candidate
for one of the coordinate axes of the slice.

In order to form a Cartesian coordinate system that describes the slice
in the usual way (mapping equations to shapes in the way we usually expect),
the other coordinate axis of the slice should be perpendicular to the
$w$-axis, and the unit of measurement along that axis should be equal to
the unit along the $w$-axis.
That is, we want to set up a coordinate axis along the line
$y = x\tan\theta$ in the $x,y$ plane;
and if we call this the $u$-axis, then we want the point
$(u,w) = (1,0)$ in the plane of the slice to be the point
$(x,y,w) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0).$

In order to evaluate $f(z)$ (or $g(z)$) at any given value of $u,$ we
can write $z = u\cos\theta + iu \sin\theta,$
or more simply, $z = u e^{i\theta}.$
Observing that $\bar z = u e^{-i\theta},$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+z^2}
&= \frac{1}{1+u^2 e^{i2\theta}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1+u^2 e^{i2\theta}}
      \cdot\frac{1+u^2 e^{-i2\theta}}{1+u^2 e^{-i2\theta}} \\
&= \frac{1+u^2 e^{-i2\theta}}
   {1+u^2 (e^{-i2\theta} + e^{-i2\theta}) + e^{i2\theta}e^{-i2\theta} u^4}\\
&= \frac{1+(\cos(2\theta))u^2 - i(\sin(2\theta))u^2}
        {1+(2\cos(2\theta))u^2 + u^4}\\
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
f(z) = \mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)
= \frac{1+(\cos(2\theta))u^2}{1+(2\cos(2\theta))u^2 + u^4}
$$
and
$$
g(z) = \mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)
= \frac{-(\sin(2\theta))u^2}{1+(2\cos(2\theta))u^2 + u^4}
$$

We can now relax our constraints on $\theta$; if we let
$\theta$ be any real number, the angles $\theta_1$ and 
$\theta_2 = \theta_1 - \pi$
both specify the same slice of the three-dimensional graph,
except that the $u$-axis for $\theta_1 - \pi$ runs in the opposite
direction from the $u$-axis for $\theta_1.$

If you just pick angles randomly then you will almost certainly end
up with transcendental coefficients in these equations;
but if you simply set either $\cos\theta$  or $\sin\theta$
to a rational number between $-1$ and $1$ and apply the usual
trigonometric identities, you will get relatively reasonable coefficients
(rational numbers and/or square roots of rational numbers).

### Examples

The table below shows the functions we obtain by “slicing” the graph of $\frac1{1+z^2}$ at a few different angles:
$\theta=0$ (slicing along the $x$ axis), $\theta=\frac\pi4$ radians ($45$ degrees, slicing along the line $y=x$), and $\theta=\frac\pi2$ ($90$ degrees, slicing along the $y$ axis).

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\theta&\ &\cos(2\theta)&\ &\sin(2\theta)&\ &\mathrm{Re}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+z^2}\right)&\ & \mathrm{Im}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+z^2}\right) \\
\hline
0        && 1&& 0 && \dfrac{1+u^2}{1+2u^2+u^4} = \dfrac{1}{1+u^2} && 0\\
\frac\pi4&& 0&& 1 && \dfrac{1}{1+u^4} && \dfrac{-u^2}{1+u^4} \\
\frac\pi2&&-1&& 0 && \dfrac{1-u^2}{1-2u^2+u^4} = \dfrac{1}{1-u^2} && 0\\
\end{array}

### Alternatives

In general, if you write $z = x + iy,$ then $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ can also be written as functions of the real and imaginary components of $z$:
\begin{align}
f(x, y) &= f(x + iy) = \frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}, \\
g(x, y) &= g(x + iy) = \frac{-2xy}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}.
\end{align}
A "slice through the origin" gives a line in the complex plane with
an equation like the following in $x$ and $y$:
$$ Ax + By = 0,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are not both zero.
Take $A = 0$ and you have the equation of the $x$-axis;
take $B = 0$ and you have the $y$-axis;
take $A = \tan\theta$ and $B = -1$ and you have a line rotated by an angle
$\theta$ from the $x$-axis, with  slope $m = \tan\theta$
and equivalent equation $y = mx.$

Note that after you "split" $z$ into real and imaginary components
$x$ and $y,$ you generally require *both* components in order to
evaluate $f$ and $g$ at any value $z.$
If you simply erase $y$ from the formula for $f$ above, you end up with
$\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2+4x^2},$ which you can easily verify is 
not a faithful formula for $\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right).$
On the other hand, if you "slice" a function such as $f(x,y)$ along a line
through the origin, you have something that resembles a function of
one (real-valued) coordinate plotted in a plane,
that is, a single-parameter real function.
There should be a way to write $f$ as such a function.

Any resolution to this question is going to come down to choosing
one real-valued variable as an independent coordinate, and using some
functions of that variable as the $x$ and $y$ values in $f(x,y).$
In the question, one method is explored in which we set
$f(x,y) = f(x, x\tan\theta).$  That is, we use $x$ for $x$ itself and
$x\tan\theta$ for $y.$
This makes it possible to plot $f$ as a function of $x$ along along any line
whose equation can be written $y = x\tan\theta.$
It is not possible to plot $f$ in this way along the $y$ axis.

Another method is to set $f(x,y) = f(y\cot\theta, y).$
This makes it possible to plot $f$ as a function of $y$ along along any line
whose equation can be written $x = y\cot\theta,$
that is, along any line through the origin except the $x$-axis.

You can use the second method to describe the slice of $f$ along the $y$-axis
as a single-parameter real function,
and the first method to describe any other slice of $f$ through the origin.
If you apply this method along lines at angles near $90$ degrees 
(but not at $90$ degrees exactly),
you can observe that the function increases from $1$ toward a maximum value,
then falls to a negative minimum value, then increases asymptotically to zero;
as the angle of the line approaches $90$ degrees, the maximum and minimum
values get more extreme and also occur at $x$-values closer and closer to zero.
At $90$ degrees exactly, the function increases to infinity and then from
negative infinity back up to zero, which is consistent with the trend of the
other functions, but rather than doing this at an input value of zero
(to which the extreme points of the other functions were converging),
it does this at the input value $1.$

Alternatively, you can use the first method just to describe the slice of $f$ 
along the $x$-axis, and use the second method for the other slices.
This gives quite different results (most of the time) compared to the
previous paragraph, but the results are just as valid.

Yet another alternative is to set $f(x,y) = f(x, x\tan\theta)$
when slicing along any line up to $45$ degrees from the $x$-axis
(that is, any line $y = mx$ where $-1 \leq m \leq 1)$,
and set $f(x,y) = f(y\cot\theta, y)$ when slicing at any other angle.
A nice thing about this is that the two methods match up perfectly 
along the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x,$ which are the lines at exactly
the angles where we switch from one method to the other.

The method I described above is just another method for reducing $f$
to a single-parameter real function.
In that method, we set $f(x,y) = f(u\cos\theta, u\sin\theta).$
Along a line at angle $\theta$ from the $x$-axis, 
where $\theta$ is a constant,
this reduces $f$ to a function of the real variable $u.$
It can also be viewed as using polar coordinates to describe points
in the complex plane, with $u$ as the radius from the origin.
The formulas I gave for $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ in terms of $u$ are just
what you get if you substitute $x = u\cos\theta$ and $y = u\sin\theta$
in the formulas for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y).$
(Note that then $x^2 - y^2 = u^2 \cos(2\theta)$ and $2xy = u^2 \sin(2\theta).$)

And these are merely a few of the infinite number of alternative methods.
You can take your pick or come up with another that you prefer.

---

### Appendix

Here are some reasons why I personally prefer the method I described in the first part of this answer,
writing $z = u\cos\theta + i u\sin\theta.$

In general, except when $\theta = 0$ the 
$x$-axis does not actually lie in the slice taken through the origin.
In effect, the method of setting $f(z) = f(x, x\tan\theta)$
is a  projection of  the $x$-axis onto the plane of the slice
(or vice versa).
The projection is parallel to the $y$-axis, so when
$\theta$ is near $\frac\pi2,$ that is, when the slice is nearly parallel
to the $y$-axis, the projection onto the slice is "stretched"
in the horizontal  direction.
This can have some weird results.

For example, consider the plot of the real function $h(z) = |z|^2.$
The graph $w = h(x+iy)$ is a paraboloid of revolution around the $w$-axis,
that is, every slice is a parabola of the same shape.
But if we take the slice at $\theta = \frac32$
(that is, rotated about $85.94$ degrees from the $x$-axis),
and plot $w$ as a function of $x$ in that slice, 
we find that in this slice,
$$
w = \left|x + i\tan\left(\tfrac32\right)\right|^2
= \left(\sec^2\left(\tfrac32\right)\right) x^2 
\approx 199.85 x^2,
$$
although in the slice for $\theta = 0$ the equation is $w = x^2.$

How can two slices have such different equations
when they have the same shape?
The answer is that we have used an unnatural, distorted coordinate system
for the slice at $\theta = \frac32.$
This coordinate system works weirdly in that slice.
(And as we know, it doesn't work at all in the slice $\theta = \frac\pi2.$)

If you set up a $u$-axis in the slice, however, then no matter what
value of $\theta$ you use you will always find that the equation
of the slice is $w = u^2,$ which describes the actual
shape of the slice in the way we usually expect.
And when $\theta = \frac\pi2,$ then $u = y,$
so we end up using the $y$ axis instead of the $x$ axis
just as in the other answer.

Comment: Do you know how to slice a function at an angle and not through the origin and not parallel to an axis?

Comment: (1+(cos(2*theta))*u^2)/(1+(2*cos(theta))*u^2+u^4)  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B(cos(2*theta))*u%5E2)%2F(1%2B(2*cos(theta))*u%5E2%2Bu%5E4)

Comment: theta = zero gives 1/(u+1): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B(cos(2*0))*u%5E2)%2F(1%2B(2*cos(0))*u%5E2%2Bu%5E4)   However, theta = 90 does not give 1/(u-1) but instead gives http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B(cos(2*90))*u%5E2)%2F(1%2B(2*cos(90))*u%5E2%2Bu%5E4)  Does this mean that the slice at 90degrees does not equal 1/(u-1)?

Comment: Note that you did not separate z^2 into real and imaginary components before slicing and that is where the distortion arose.

Comment: Re[(x + I y)^2]=x^2-y^2

Comment: It's a good thing you checked those formulas in Wolfram Alpha, because it turns out I wrote $\cos\theta$ in some places where I should have written $\cos(2\theta).$ I have fixed that error.

Comment: In your Appendix you do not separate the cartesian equation into real and imaginary components before slicing, which makes your debunking of  Daniel Fischer's method inaccurate at a minimum. See the other answer for example of how this is done.

Comment: There is no attempt to "debunk" anything. Mathematically, you have many alternative methods to plot the slices of the function. I have merely described a method that I prefer, and tried to explain why I prefer it. Your mileage may vary, as they say. I have added descriptions of a few other methods for comparison.

Comment: You make it sound like there are two methods: ue^(i*2*theta) and x*tan(theta) that are equivalent. I want to point out that at theta=45 that these two methods yeild different results. 1/(u^4+1) and 1/(4*x^2+1) respectively. How to show which is correct?

Comment: Since $x = u\cos\theta = (\sqrt2)x$ when $\theta$ is $45$ degrees, the results come out the same, given consistent data (the correct formula using $x$ is $1/(4x^4 + 1)$; check the math). What is different is the particular functional representation; using $u$ as the function parameter gives a different function than using $x.$ Note that _neither_ of those functions is the same as the function you started with, whose parameter is a complex number.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732916/how-to-slice-a-function

Comment: I edited the other answer to include a third method that agrees with your method completely.