# How many complex functions reduce to a given x-y function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

A 2D or x-y coordinate function has a complex analog, which is formed by replacing x with with the complex variable z. That function can then be separated into real and imaginary parts. Graphing the real part, produces a 3D graph with the vertical slice along the x-axis [corresponding to the original 2D function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463174/how-to-slice-re1-1z-into-a-cartesian-function-for-any-angle). However, it doesn't seem impossible that another real component of a complex function somewhere may in fact reduce to this same original 2D function. Is it possible to know if there are other such functions? If yes, is there a method of searching for such a function?

Comment: Is your original function a map $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$? It isn't clear what you mean. Can you furnish an example of the "original" and the "complexified" function?

Comment: @MPW I believe the answer is yes, for more info see the link in my question.