# Is there a field of math that studies the relation between 2d and 3d graphs?

Tags: graphing-functions

I mean graphs where a slice of a 3d surface  yeilsds a 2d graph.
[How To Slice $Re(1/(1+z))$ Into A Cartesian Function For Any Angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463174/how-to-slice-re1-1z-into-a-cartesian-function-for-any-angle)

Comment: I think it's called complex analysis, but thanks for pointing me to your earlier, very interesting question.

Comment: @ DavidK Complex analysis is fairly large. Is there a particular area of complex analysis that deals with this? Something to do with Functions perhapse?

Comment: Actually your earlier question uses bits and pieces of a few things; complex functions and linear algebra come to mind. It's not quite a real three-D space nor a complex space, however, due to the combination of complex input and real output of the graphed function. But you can relate it to the intersection of surfaces in real Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138808/plotting-a-2d-slice-of-a-3d-function