# How to rotate the graph $z=f(x)$ towards $y$ so that $z=f(x,y)$?

Tags: graphing-functions

Given z=x^3 rotate this curve towars the y axis about the z axis so that z=f(x,y) but with the same curve as z=x^3. Write z=f(x,y)=f(x^3,theta). Eventually z=y^3 when theta =90 degrees. I am guessing that the projection onto the x and y axes are streatched: z=a*x^3+b*y^3 may be a solution? Could we say z=r^3.

Comment: $z=0$ in the $xy$ plane.

Answer (score 1):

When we rotate a point $(x,y)$ by $\theta$ degrees counterclockwise, our new point $(x',y')$ is defined to be $x'=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$ and $y'=y\cos\theta+x\sin\theta$ (see **[here](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/RotationDerivation.pdf)** for an explanation of this).

To apply this method to the curve $z=x^3$, replacing $x$ with $x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$ will rotate the $x$ and $y$ axes by $\theta$ degrees. However, we want the curve to rotate, not the axes. Replacing $x$ with $x\cos(-\theta)-y\sin(-\theta)$, which can be simplified to $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta$, will rotate the axes in the opposite direction, effectively rotating the curve in the direction we want.  The result is: $$z=(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)^3.$$ And yes, when $\theta=90^\circ$, $z=(x\cos90^\circ+y\sin90^\circ)^3$ or $z=y^3$ (because $\cos90^\circ=0$ and $\sin90^\circ=1$).

Here is a graph (created at https://www.geogebra.org/3d) of $z=x^3$ (in green) and $z=(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^3$ (in brown):

[image: Rotation of $z=x^3$]

Comment: What if I were to try rotating a surface? say : $$Re(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)})=\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2}$$ Replacing x gives: $$Re(\frac{1}{(1+z^2)})=\frac{1+(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2-y^2}{(1+(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2-y^2)^2+4(x\cos45^\circ+y\sin45^\circ)^2y^2}$$

Comment: Also replace y with $y\cos\theta-x\sin\theta$, since we are rotating about the z-axis;  I don't know too much about surfaces, but I believe this would do the trick.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes for more information about rotating points, conic sections, etc.

Comment: x' = x cos(theta) +y sin(theta) , y'=-x sin(theta)+y cos(theta)

Comment: Seems like z=(xcos(120)+ysin(120))^3 is a surface not a line?