# I can find slices of a surface for any angle through the vertical axis, but I am not certain what the equation of the surface is.

Tags: surfaces

I can find slices of a surface for any angle through the vertical axis, but I am not certain what the equation of the surface is.

Equation along x-axis: $z=1/(1+x^2)$

Equation along y-axis:$z=1/(1-y^2)$

Equation at 45 degrees: $z=1/(t^4+1)$, where t is the line in the x-y plane at 45 
degrees.

Equation at 30 degrees: $z=1/((9/4*t^2)+1)$, where t is the line in the x-y plane at 30 degrees.

Feel free to ask for the equation of a slice through any angle. 
What is the equation of the surface?

[image]

Comment: In the 45 degree version, what is $t$? Is it the distance along that line from the origin? Same question for the 30 degree case.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes

Comment: Can you give a rule or algorithm by which we can figure out the equation for any slice without having to ask you for each angle?

Comment: Is this related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463174/how-to-slice-re1-1z-into-a-cartesian-function-for-any-angle? The equations for the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and $45$ degrees match, but the $30$-degree equation seems different, which is all the more reason to need to know how that equation was obtained.

Comment: @Dale Is the graphic made on any CAS for the actual surface? What is represented by the green and  rotating vectors/arrows? a variable plane intersection around the normal as axis?

Comment: The surface passing through these 4 curves is by no means unique.  You need to give more information about it.

Comment: @OskarLimka How many sliced Need I provide?

Comment: @Dale the short answer is infinitely many (which is not very helpful, I guess). The longerish answer is to think of a two dimensional analogue: take $n+1$ points in the $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=0,\dotsc,n$ with $x_i=x_j\Leftrightarrow i=j$, there are infinitely many functions satisfying $f(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i=0,\dotsc,n$ but a unique one if $f$ is required to be a polynomial of degree $n$ or less. This example's "polynomial of degree $\leq n$" is what I mean by "more information".  Other classes of functions are rational functions.

Comment: If you are interested in one function of many (maybe infinitely so) possible, then I'd look for rational functions of two variables.  Roughly speaking rational functions of degree $(m,n)$ form a $p(m)+p(n)$ dimensional manifold where $p(k)$ is the number of linearly independent polynomials of degree $k$ in $\mathbb R^2$. From the examples you've given, I would look for $m=0$ and $n=4$.  The interpolation problem could then be reduced to that of a polynomial of $2$ variables and total degree $n$, for which a finite number of (suitably chosen) points suffices.

Comment: In my comment above I was thinking of your unknown $f(x,y)$ to be of the form $S(x,y)/P(x,y)$ where $S$ and $P$ are polynomials of $\operatorname{deg} S=m$ and $\operatorname{deg}P=n$.

Comment: If $S\equiv c\in\mathbb R$, then your problem becomes of finding a polynomial $P$ coinciding with certain one-dimensional polynomials along the "spokes" that you've described.  Since the maximal degree there was $4$, I think degree $4$ is more than enough for starters, possibly $P(x,y)=a+bx^2+cy^2+dx^2y^2$ could be enough...

Comment: @OskarLimka Perhapse we could write a lisp function to sort through the surfaces?

Comment: Usually folks try to derive a linear system for the coefficients $a, b, c, d$ in this case by imposing the conditions.