# Complex function mapping the unit circle onto an interval

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that the function $f(z) = z^2 + z^{-2}$ maps the unit circle onto the interval $[-2, 2]$.

Okay so far, doing previous questions I firstly try and find the inverse mapping. Here I considered the unit circle as $|z| = 1$. I then converted this to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

However with this question I don't know how to find the inverse mapping of the above function so I'm stuck unfortunately.

Comment: The function is not invertible, since $f(-z)=f(z)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free software / online tool to plot complex functions as maps of grids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399467/free-software-online-tool-to-plot-complex-functions-as-maps-of-grids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since our domain is the unit circle, $z$ is the form $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$

$$z^2=\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)$$

$$z^{-2}=\cos(2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta)$$

$$z^2+\frac1{z^2}=2\cos(2\theta)$$

And we are done.

Comment: Thank you! So if the domain of z is easily represented I can just pass it into the equation?

Comment: @user135567 yes you can. Here $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show two things: First, if $z$ is on the unit circle, i.e., if $z=e^{i\theta}$, then the given function maps $z$ to the interval $[-2,2]$. Also, if $x$ is a point on that interval, you want to produce a $z$ on the unit circle that maps to that $x$. Once you figure out the first part, the second part will be easier, because you'll have a function of one variable to invert.

Does that help?