# How to draw Two complex variable plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, parametrization

I have a eigenvector from some matrix.

$$(i \sin(\phi), 1+i \cos(\phi))$$
where
$$ 0\le\phi\le\pi $$ and $i=(\sqrt-1)$

I tried to draw the locus of these points on the complex plane.(it should be a branch of hyperbola)

Once I let $x=i\sin(\phi), y= 1+i\cos(\phi)$ , I could get hyperbolic curve.
$$y=1+i(1+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$

However, the problem is that $x$ is not real.

I wonder whether this is okay.

Comment: For a complex number one usually needs to draw a plane (one axis for the real part and another for the imaginary part), so for two coordinates you should be able to draw it on $\mathbb{R}^4$, which I guess you're not because I think you are a human being.

Comment: The first component of your eigenvector is imaginary, you can represent the eigenvector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In general, eigenvectors are determined up to a complex constant. When the first component is non-zero, you can normalize your eigenvector to make its first component equals to $1$ and then plot the second component.

Comment: The topic of [graphing a complex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193803/3111), which requires display of four dimensional information, has come up several times here (do a site search for `graphing complex function`).  The present Question requires fewer dimensions (looked at in one way gives us a circle in a plane), so I don't consider it a duplicate.